# Missing File Dependency in new Project Structure of Android Studio 3.3

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

With new developer version of Android Studio 3.3, Project Structure window changed. (seems to be IDEA reason, good improvement for setting basic gradle properties), but I cannot find File Dependency option in Declared Dependency.

[image]